# MATLAB function conv2

Tags: matlab

When I try to use `filter2` function of MATLAB I found that is based on the `conv2` function.

But editing this function (edit conv2) I didn't found anything, just a simple commentary.

Please, I want to know how this function (conv2) use these arguments, `hcol`, `hrow`, `image` and the `shape='same'` to compute the output image. Or where can I find the `conv2` MATLAB function?

Comment: Have a look at http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/conv2.html

Comment: The reason `edit conv2` didn't reveal any code, is that this function is not implemented as a Matlab script, but as a function from external library.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the "help" and "doc" functions to get such information on all MATLAB functions. Just write

```
help conv2
```

or

```
doc conv2
```

The help function will give you some information in the command window, while the `doc` function opens the MATLAB documentation.